# Skip automatically pop up of "Word will now convert your PDF to an editable Word document."

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I use at the moment the following command to open e read PDF

`appWord.Documents.Open(CompleteNameFile, False, True)`

But it open a dialog box saying:
"Word will now convert your PDF to an editable Word document".
And give me the options: Ok, Cancel, Help

Could anyone tell me how I could automatize the choice "OK" by command of VBA, instead of clicking?

Comment: If all else fails, sendkeys. But perhaps `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` works, but I doubt it will.

Comment: With this command DisplayAlerts = False.. nothing happens

Comment: In that case you need to use sendkeys

Comment: How can I do this with alert boxes?

Comment: The same way as always `SendKeys("{ENTER}")` but you probably need to put a wait to make sure the alert box is open when the enter key stroke is sent.